# How to check in PHP if a string can be transformed to integer?

Tags: php, string, integer

I have strings of the following form: "37", "42", "7".

I need to transform them into integers. I can use `intval`. But I want to check if the string was in the expected format (by not expected format I mean, for example, "abc" or "a7"). How can I do it before or after use of the `intval`?

As far as I know `intval` returns 1 if the argument was not in the appropriate format. If it is the case, there is not way to check if the argument was the good format just by analyzing the output of the `intval`.

Comment: As far as I know intval returns 1 if the argument was not in the appropriate format.  // it's wrong.

Comment: intval("42istheans");/*42*/ intval("string") //0

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
ctype_digit()
```

http://ro2.php.net/ctype_digit

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for [filter_var](http://php.net/filter_var).

```
$input = '5';
filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT); // returns 5
$input = 'asdf';
filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT); // returns false
```

There are also many other options you can pass into this function.  I believe it was designed as a way to validate form submissions.

Answer (score 1):

ctype_digit($x) && ($x == floor($x))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php). It should return true if it is a number, false if there are letters in the mix.

Answer (score 0):

Mediocre solution, but you could do:

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]*$/', $value)
```

Answer (score -2):

How about (int)$value == $value?

This would cast the value to an int, so that the left hand is definately an integer, and then checks if an untyped comparison is true.

Comment: `var_dump(((int)"xyz") == "xyz");` returns true. Now `===` might work

Comment: (int)"xyz" becomes 0.  Then when you compare an int to a string the string to casted to an int. What you're really suggesting is (int)"xyz" == (int)"xyz";